# AzureML - CLIv2 - Mount Datastore

Tags: python, azure, azureml-python-sdk, azuremlsdk, azure-ml-pipelines

I've created a simple script in order to understand the interaction between AzureML and AzureStorage in AzureML CLIv2.

I would like to download MNIST Dataset and store in on a datastore.

First, i declared my datastore in AzureML :
[image]

I've created a very simple script in order to download MNIST Dataset (torchvision) like that :

```py
import os
import argparse
import logging
from torchvision.datasets import MNIST,CIFAR10

def main():
    """Main function of the script."""

    # input and output arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--dst_dir", type=str, help="Directory where to write data")
    parser.add_argument('--dataset_name',type=str,choices=['MNIST','CIFAR10'])
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print(vars(args))
    root_path = os.path.join(args.dst_dir,args.dataset_name)
    if args.dataset_name=="MNIST":
        print(f"Download {args.dataset_name} => {root_path}")
        data_train=MNIST(root=root_path,train=True,download=True)
        data_test=MNIST(root=root_path,train=False,download=True)
    elif args.dataset_name=="CIFAR10":
        print(f"Download {args.dataset_name} => {root_path}")
        data_train=CIFAR10(root=root_path,train=True,download=True)
        data_test=CIFAR10(root=root_path,train=False,download=True)
    else:
        print("Unknown Dataset......")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In order to launch the download on the correct datastore, i've created :

- An Environment (Working)
- A Compute Cluster (Working)
- An entry script :

```py
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient
from azure.ai.ml import command
from azure.ai.ml import Input, Output
from azure.ai.ml.entities import Environment
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential, InteractiveBrowserCredential
from azure.ai.ml.constants import AssetTypes,InputOutputModes
from datetime import datetime

## => CODE to get Environment
## => CODE to get Compute

component_name = f"DataWrapper-{datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')}"
print(component_name)
data_wrapper_component = command(
    name=component_name,
    display_name=component_name,
    description="Download a TorchVision Dataset in AzureStorage...",
    inputs={
        "dataset_name":"MNIST",
    },
    outputs={
        "dst_dir":Output(
            type=AssetTypes.URI_FOLDER,
            folder="azureml://datastores/torchvision_data",
            mode=InputOutputModes.RW_MOUNT),
    },
    # The source folder of the component
    code="./code", # On ajoute tout le code folder...
    command="""python components/datawrapper/datawrapper.py \
            --dst_dir ${{outputs.dst_dir}}                  \
            --dataset_name ${{inputs.dataset_name}}
            """,
    compute=cpu_compute_target,
    experiment_name="datawrapper",
    is_deterministic=False,
    environment=f"{pipeline_job_env.name}:{pipeline_job_env.version}"
)


returned_job = ml_client.create_or_update(data_wrapper_component)
aml_url = returned_job.studio_url
print("Monitor your job at", aml_url)
```

The job is executed correctly, but the datastore is still empty :
[image]
[image]

I tryed to replace :

```py
folder="azureml://datastores/torchvision_data"
```

by

```py
path="azureml://datastores/torchvision_data"
```

but it is not working :
[image]

My source documentation are :

- https://github.com/Azure/azureml-examples/blob/main/sdk/python/resources/datastores/datastore.ipynb
- https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/machine-learning/how-to-read-write-data-v2?tabs=cli
- https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/azure/machine-learning/how-to-read-write-data-v2?tabs=python#write-data-in-a-job

**Did i make something wrong when i mount the output Folder ?**

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem with the help of MS customer Engineers.

In the documentation :
[image]

We need to be very careful with the structure of the path :

> azureml://datastores/**<data_store_name>**/paths/**<path>**

The two part in **bold** should be filled ! In my case :
Instead of :

> azureml://datastores/torchvision-data/

It was necessary to write :

> azureml://datastores/torchvision-data/**paths/**

In order to indicate that i was in the root directory of my datastore.

Then the command becomes :

```py
data_wrapper_component = command(
    name=component_name,
    display_name=component_name,
    description="Download a TorchVision Dataset in AzureStorage...",
    inputs={
        "dataset_name":"MNIST",
    },
    outputs={
        "dst_dir":Output(
            type=AssetTypes.URI_FOLDER,
            path="azureml://datastores/torchvision_data/paths/",
            mode=InputOutputModes.RW_MOUNT),
    },
    # The source folder of the component
    code="./code", # On ajoute tout le code folder...
    command="""python components/datawrapper/datawrapper.py \
            --dst_dir ${{outputs.dst_dir}}                  \
            --dataset_name ${{inputs.dataset_name}}
            """,
    compute=cpu_compute_target,
    experiment_name="datawrapper",
    is_deterministic=False,
    environment=f"{pipeline_job_env.name}:{pipeline_job_env.version}"
)
```

Hope it will help !